# TypeScript un Array como tipo de un objeto

Tags: array, typescript, javascript-objeto

Estoy intentando crear un objeto que contenga dos tipos de array y si bien el código compila correctamente, en la consola del navegador me dice que la variable del tipo array no está definida cuando intento hacer un push() dentro del bucle for (ERROR TypeError: "chartData.data is undefined").¿por qué?

Gracias!

ngOnInit(): void {

```
type chartDataStruct = {
  data:number[],
  backgroundColor:string[],
  label:string
}

let chartData = {} as chartDataStruct;


for (let index = 0; index<24; index++)
{
  chartData.data.push(23);
  chartData.backgroundColor.push("red");
}
chartData.label = "Descarga";

console.log(chartData);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro por qué no funcionó la declaración anterior, pero la cambié por una definición directa del objeto de la siguiente forma:

```
let chartData = {
  data:[],
  backgroundColor:[],
  label:""
};
```

Funcionó correctamente.

Comment: No te funciona porque una cosa es especificar el tipo de dato: `type ChartDataType = { data:number[] }` y otra asignar un valor al campo: `const chartData = { data: [] }`

Al crear el chartData como `{}` lo que tienes es un objeto vacío, por mucho que le hagas un cast a `ChartDataType`

Comment: Hacer `let chartData = {} as chartDataStruct;` compila unicamente porque le estas diciendo al compilador que sabes que el tipo no es el correcto, pero que pretenda que no es un error.

Answer (score 0):

Para que funcione puedes hacer esto:

```
export interface chartDataStruct = {
  //Esto no incializa las variables. Por eso te da undefined los dos arreglos.
  data:number[],
  backgroundColor:string[],
  label:string
}
```

Y despues crear tu variable:

```
let chartData= {} as chartDataStruct
```

```
for (let index = 0; index<24; index++)
{
  //Aqui debes inicializar los arreglos por que estan vacios
  if( !chartData.data ) chartData.data = []
  if( !chartData.backgroundColor) chartData.backgroundColor = []
  chartData.data.push(23);
  chartData.backgroundColor.push("red");
}
chartData.label = "Descarga";
```